# Proof verification, positive derivative real valued function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification

> Let $f$ be a differentiable in $a\in\mathbf R$. Assume $f'(a)>0$. Prove that there exists $b>a$ such that for all $x\in(a,b)$ we have $f(x)>f(a)$.

*Proof.* $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ exists, so for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|x-a|<\delta$ implies $\left\vert\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}-f'(a) \right\vert<\varepsilon$. Take $\varepsilon=\frac{f'(a)}{2}$, then $a<x<a+\delta$ implies $$\left\vert\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}-f'(a) \right\vert<\frac{f'(a)}{2} \iff \frac{f'(a)}{2}<\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}<\frac{3f'(a)}{2}$$ Multiplying by $(x-a)$ gives $$0<(x-a)\frac{f'(a)}{2}<f(x)-f(a)<(x-a)\frac{3f'(a)}{2}$$ Therefore we have $f(x)-f(a)>0$ or $f(x)>f(a)$.

Is this proof correct? More interestingly, is there a simpler method to prove this result? We have to work from the definition for this question, so I am looking for a proof that does not use the Mean Value Theorem. The proof above was provided to me by a classmate.

Comment: Your proof is correct (and simplest available) but it does not use mean value theorem as you think. It just uses derivative definition. And do say thanks to your classmate :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proof is correct. A simpler proof:

assume to the contrary , that for each $n \in \mathbb N$ there is $x_n \in (a,a+1/n)$ such that $f(x_n) \le f(a)$.

Then

(*) $ \frac{f(x_n)-f(a)}{x_n-a} \le 0$ for all $n$.

Since $x_n \to a$ we get from $(*)$: $f'(a) \le 0$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is correct, but perhaps you may find that this is a tick simpler: You know that $$0<f'(a)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$ Since, the limit on the RHS exists, you can be sure the $h\to0^+$ and $h\to0^-$ exist and are equal. Restrict attention to $h\to0^+$. Then, by the definition of the limit, there exists some $\epsilon>0$ such that, for all $0<h<\epsilon$ $$0<\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} \overset{h>0}\implies f(a+h)>f(a)$$ Letting $b=a+\epsilon$ concludes the proof.